# Best way for merging two spreadsheets with multiple keys using Python

Tags: python, excel, many-to-many

I have two spreadsheets that contain multiple columns that correspond to multiple columns. I am looking for the best way to combine them.

Using V Lookup doesn't work because it only matches the first case, where in these spreadsheets, there are multiple matches for each column.

If a spreadsheet has the columns ["IP", "Host", "Server"] they could all correspond to each of the columns in spreadsheet two ["Address", "Notes", "Server"]. This creates a many-to-many link that is hard to do in excel.

The double whammy is that it would need to use .contains logic. For example the "Host" might be 'dhdkd' and need to be found within the "Address" column as 'test@dhdkd'.

I've had troubles with the best method of doing this and I am looking to either use Excel commands, or Python (which is my flavor of code).

Comment: _"that contain multiple columns that correspond to multiple columns."_  -- I'm not sure what you are saying here.  Maybe provide an example?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as text in your question, including a sample of you input(s), your expected output, and _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research